# adding two ranges with range number to Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting Range1  and  Range2  from database. Dataset is like below.

Range1    Range2

AB100     XY200

AB300     XY400

AB500     XY600

I have to bind these ranges to a  Drop Down List  as list items includung range number in my application.

So list item should be like ==> 1    AB100     XY200 . When user selects a range I have to pass Range1  and  Range2 to database.

How can I bind the two ranges with range number to Drop Down List.

Regards,

JN

Answer (score 0):

I feel you have to create you custom range, which could be like AB100-XY200, AB300-XY200 (basically using some spilter to identify two values)

Then in the dropdown on selected server event , u can split the two values and pass them to the database.